# How to insert a variable into a query parameter?

Tags: php, query

I need to put a variable into query parameter.

I have this situation:

```
$variable = get_field(loop_category);

$catquery = new WP_Query( 'category_name=***VARIABLE-HERE***');
while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Errr, are you talking about this:

```
$variable = get_field('loop_category');
$args = array(
    'category_name' => $variable,
);
$catquery = new WP_Query($args);
while ($catquery->have_posts()) {
    $catquery->the_post();

    // Do your thing

}
```

If so, this is basic PHP and has nothing to do with WordPress - even though this is used in its context.